# Is it possible to add new scopes to an already verified Google app?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am currently working with Google APIs and I am setting up the scopes I need in order to get verified. It is possible some day in the future we may want to add new functionality with new scopes. I understand that to get verified Google does the Scope Verification check but what would the process be if I wanted to add a new scope to an app that is already verified? Do we go through the entire verification process again or is there an abridged one for apps that already have been verified?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Yes, you'll need to request another verification by Google. Previously approved scopes will continue to be approved. However, any new scopes will display the ugly warning screen to users until Google approves them.

Here's an example of what it looks like in my GCP app. Google shows the previously approved scope as still being approved and appropriately flags the newly added scope as requiring a review:

[image: example of GCP app with a mix of approved and unapproved scopes]