# Will Google remove the existing app verification if we add more scopes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

We have an existing app in google which is up and running in production. The app has the below scopes.

1. openid
2. drive.file

Now we want to update the scopes for our new requirements. So, the new scope needed are,

1. openid
2. drive
3. userinfo.email

So, if we add the new scopes to the existing app and apply for verification will this affect the existing applications' verified status - in the meantime of google approving the new scopes.

We have followed all the steps like taking a video, explaining the reason and everything to apply for verification with these new scopes. But we want to make sure the existing app should not go unverified just because we requested adding new scopes to it. This will affect our existing customers using some other set of features with existing scopes.

We have even created a support ticket in google - but did not get a clear response for this query.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: From what I see, the scopes that have already been verified won't be affected in this situation. Only the new ones that you'll be requesting. You may find these Stack Oveflow posts similar to your question as well: [Adding new Scope to Google OAuth Consent Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75854967) and [Is it possible to add new scopes to an already verified Google app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200817)